# Can't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, linux

I am have trouble connecting to a mysql server. The error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: What code are you using to connect to the server? Is socket based communication set up?

Comment: We really need to see the code involved in connecting to the database (this really isn't a programming question without it).

Answer (score 1):

First please check if the file /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock exists.If not then create one in the same path with no content in it.And then do a mysql stop start using /etc/init.d/mysql stop(for stop) and /etc/init.d/mysql start .If even then mysql does not work , try user265130 solution.

Answer (score 0):

try to locate the valid socket for your connection.

if your using zend, you can configure it like this:

```
db.config.unix_socket = "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.sock"
```

Comment: I just install slackware and I do not think that install zend by default what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect with '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'. You might have to also so supply the port (-P 3306)

Answer (score 0):

As a root user type in
**mysqld_safe** 
and then from other terminal type your normal starting command like
mysql -u USERNAME -p
and you wont get the above error..